# CMake <PROJECT-NAME>_SOURCE_DIR Variable Scope

Tags: c++, variables, cmake

Based on the [thread "cmake variable scope, add_subdirectory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891447/cmake-variable-scope-add-subdirectory), the CMake [set](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/set.html) command will set the variable in the current scope only, unless the `PARENT_SCOPE` parameter is specified.

Recently when I was looking at the [project](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/project.html) command, per CMake doc, variables `<PROJECT-NAME>_SOURCE_DIR` and `<PROJECT-NAME>_BINARY_DIR` will be set. But it didn't mention what is the scope of these variables. Can these variable be used in other subdirectory? For example:

`|- root
| |- CMakeLists.txt  // add_subdirectory(proj1); add_subdirectory(proj2)
| |
| |- proj1
| |  |- CMakeLists.txt  // project(proj1)
| |
| |- proj2
| |  |- CMakeLists.txt  // Does this have access to proj1_SOURCE_DIR or 
                        // poj1_BINARY_DIR?`

What about variables for other command like `Find_Package`? What is the scope of the `<Module>_FOUND` variable? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer by taking a close look at the cmake source code. The project command is actually setting cache entry at the top level. In this way, `$proj1_SOURCE_DIR` and `$proj1_BINARY_DIR` will be available to other sibling scopes.

https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/420874bfaa20772525c60b20d1ee5b6ef5ed9298/Source/cmProjectCommand.cxx#L30-L40

In sum, for command project(proj1), cmake will do:

`set(proj1_SOURCE_DIR, CACHE STATIC "")
set(proj1_BINARY_DIR, CACHE STATIC "")`

Unlike regular `set(var value)`, the cache entry could be shared by other sibling scope.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [`project`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/project.html):

> The top-level CMakeLists.txt file for a project must contain a
>   literal, direct call to the project() command; loading one through the
>   include() command is not sufficient. If no such call exists CMake will
>   implicitly add one to the top that enables the default languages (C
>   and CXX).

So, those variables are already there and propagate scopes down the layout.

Now, the `project` command should normally be used once in project, since it sets up various flags. If your other sub-projects are also required to be built by themselves as standalone, then a common idiom is to have a check like this:

```
if(CURRENT_CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR)
  project(foo CXX)

  # other stuff here
endif()
```

Please note that the `PARENT_SCOPE` is useful in the context of functions and their call sites.

Comment: "The scope for.....So, the proj2 cmake file shouldn't have access to proj1_SOURCE_DIR, etc."  I don't  think this is true.

Comment: yeah, that wasn't very clear. The truth is that they behave the same as other vars, but they get special treatment on **when** they are defined. Updated my answer to reflect that. Also note, that the order of `add_subdirectory` still plays the usual role.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. You can take a look at my findings and see if I missed anything.