# How to include two different versions of the same dependency in a CMake project?

Tags: cmake, dependency-management, cmake-modules

I have ExternalProject in both versions 1.2 and 2.2 present in my system. ExternalProject is a CMake project and CMake finds the both versions without trouble when I ask for them. Command `find_package(ExternalProject 1.2 EXACT)` finds version 1.2 and `find_package(ExternalProject 2.2 EXACT)` finds version 2.2.

Versions 1 and 2 are not compatible with each other. The APIs are completely different.

I have a CMake project, MyProject, which has two targets, targetOne and targetTwo. TargetOne uses ExternalProject 1.2 and TargetTwo uses ExternalProject 2.2.

The below code does not do what I want. The same external dependency is not looked up twice. The compilation of TargetTwo fails. Does CMake support this scenario in any way? (except by renaming the ExternalProject version 2 and compiling it in a different location).

```
project(MyProject)

find_package(ExternalProject 1.2 EXACT)
add_executable(targetOne target_one.c)
target_link_libraries(targetOne ExternalProject::externalProject)

find_package(ExternalProject 2.2 EXACT)
add_executable(targetTwo target_two.c)
target_link_libraries(targetTwo ExternalProject::externalProject)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't mix targets with the same names in the same `CMakeLists.txt`. Use different `CMakeLists.txt` - one for each [executable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html) target. Use [`add_subdirectory`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html) for this.

- project ./CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(MyProject)
add_subdirectory(folder_one)
add_subdirectory(folder_two)
```

- ./folder_one/CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(ExternalProject 1.2 EXACT)
add_executable(targetOne target_one.c)
target_link_libraries(targetOne ExternalProject::externalProject)
```

- ./folder_two/CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(ExternalProject 2.2 EXACT)
add_executable(targetTwo target_two.c)
target_link_libraries(targetTwo ExternalProject::externalProject)
```

Also, for [scope changing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6891527/6547185) you can use the [`function`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/function.html)

Comment: This works. Though it must be noted that CMakeCache.txt only contains one `ExternalProject_DIR:PATH`, the last found, i.e. for version 2.2 in this case. This probably has no practical meaning if the projects are found with Find*.cmake file or via CMake package cache, `~/.cmake/packages`. If the package location is specified on the command line, e.g. `-D ExternalProject_ROOT=<dir>`, then this approach will not work.